# Minus tool is creating pixelated boxes on output raster using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, arcgis-10.6

I am using ArcGIS 10.6. I am trying to see the difference between two rasters from two time periods, 2018 and 2015, by using the minus tool. The output raster it is giving me have these weird pixelated boxes throughout the whole raster. I have attached a photo to better understand what I am talking about.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Is there something I am doing wrong?

The rasters I am using both have a cell size size of 1 with the same projection. I have tried going into the environment settings and specifying the 2018 as the snap raster as well.[image]

Comment: One of them is integer?

Comment: How would I determine that? Sorry a little new at this.